# Google cloud device to device messaging without app server in android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to know if it is possible in google cloud messaging api to send messages directly from one android device to another without relying on our app server. I don't have a server so is it possible to send messages device to device through gcm?

Comment: possible difficult to implement without server. because you need to know the device registration_ids(sent by gcm) of each other.

Comment: if somehow i get the registration_id of a device from server. Then can i send a message to this device directly from another device.

Comment: do i just need registration_id of the device to send message directly.

Comment: yes. then its simple

Answer (score 1):

GCM supports device to device messaging. However, your devices would need to somehow know registration ids of each other, which is hardly achievable without coordination from your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Currently sending a device to device message is not possible with GCM, even if the two devices have exchanged InstanceId tokens.